# Classical analogy of a parallel transport

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry

This perhaps may be very naive question, but could one consider an analogy to [the parallel transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport) (as defined in this Wikipedia article) being a ball rolling on a flat table surface? If so, is then such an example also an example of holonomy or not?